# mapDispatchToProps not passing function to class

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using componentDidUpdate to send state to dispatch. At the moment I'm getting the error `this.props.handleSubmit is not a function`. When I log `this.props` I can't see the function in the log, even though I'm passing it in via mapDispatchToProps. Why might this be?

Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PlayerCard from "../PlayerCard";
import Shuffler from "../Shuffler";

class MatchCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: 0,
      winner: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevState, handleSubmit) {
    if (this.state.winner !== prevState.winner) {
      this.props.handleSubmit(this.state.winner);
    }
  }

  render(key, players) {
    const { handleClick } = this.props;
    let arr = this.props.players;

    const checkSelected = (value) => {
      return !this.state.selected ? value : 0;
    };

    return (
      <div
        className={`${
          this.state.selected ? "pointer-events-none" : null
        } mt-4 mb-4`}
      >
        <>
          <PlayerCard
            player={arr[0]}
            selected={this.state.selected === 1}
            handleClick={() =>
              this.setState({ selected: checkSelected(1), winner: arr[0] })
            }
            handleDispatch={this.handleSubmit}
          />
          <PlayerCard
            player={arr[1]}
            selected={this.state.selected === 2}
            handleClick={() =>
              this.setState({ selected: checkSelected(2), winner: arr[1] })
            }
            handleDispatch={this.handleSubmit}
          />
        </>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MatchCard;
```

mapDispatchToProps

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MatchCard from "./MatchCard";
import { setWinners } from "../../data/actions/state";

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  handleSubmit: (winner) => dispatch(setWinners(winner)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MatchCard);
```

PlayerCard

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class PlayerCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        key={this.props.key}
        className={`bg-${
          this.props.selected ? "blue-400" : "red-400"
        } h-64 w-64 flex justify-center shadow-xl focus:shadow-outline`}
        onClick={this.props.handleClick}
      >
        <p className="text-white">{this.props.player}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerCard;
```

Comment: Which component are you using? The one default exported from `MatchCard` or the one default exported from where you decorate it with the `connect` HOC? You've also mixed/messed up the function signatures of the react lifecycle functions. `componentDidUpdate` takes previous props, previous state, and snapshot, and render takes none.

Comment: I'm using the default exported from MatchCard

Comment: Ok, that is what I figured, it won't get `handleSubmit` injected into it's props, so that is why it's undefined.

Comment: I think Drew's right: in the component where you wrote `<MatchCard ... />`, did you import `MatchCard` from the file where your `mapDispatchToProps` lies (good) or from `MatchCard` itself (bad)?

Comment: Sorry - misread your question (it's late where I am). The default is exported from where you see the `connect` HOC

Comment: They both are default exported, my question is which one you are importing and trying to use elsewhere? The one decorated with the `connect` HOC is the one you likely meant to use. Can you update your question to include all the places a "MatchCard" component is being used?

Comment: Just double checked and the parent component was calling `MatchCard` itself. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you reversed the order of [componentDidUpdate's parameters](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). It should be `prevProps` then `prevState`. Though you can use other names. Also keep in mind that `handleSubmit` is only one prop in either `this.props` or `prevProps` (you shouldn't give a param of `componentDidUpdate` the name `handleSubmit`, it's confusing).

Because of this inversion your `this.state.winner !== prevState.winner` is always false (`prevProps` which you called `prevState` has no `winner` attribute, hence your `prevState.winner` is `undefined`).

Not quite sure what's the use for your `handleDispatch`, but the `this.handleSubmit` you're passing it isn't correct: it should be `this.props.handleSubmit`.

Maybe the `this.props.handleSubmit is not a function` error you're getting is thrown from `PlayerCard`. That would make sense. Please elaborate and/or give an excerpt from `PlayerCard` so that we can help you.

Comment: Thanks - I've added an excerpt from PlayerCard. I'm using dispatch to send the winner state to an array in my redux state - MatchCard has both a child component (PlayerCard) and a parent component